# xslt variable with xml structure

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to get into a variable the internal structure of a node, the issue is that the node has different paths by different reasons. What I am doing until now is

```
<xsl:variable name="my_variable">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="One/Path/To/TheNode">
      <xsl:value-of select="One/Path/To/TheNode"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="One/Different/Path/To/TheNode">
      <xsl:value-of select="One/Different/Path/To/TheNode"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="//TheNode"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

And then if I use this variable to get some subnode doing:

```
   <xsl:variable name="other_variable" select="$my_variable/Subnode"/>
```

I get this error in runtime `XPath error : Invalid type  Evaluating global variable  var/param being computed failed`, I tried too doing this:

```
<xsl:variable name="other_variable" select="ext:node-set($my_variable)/SubNode"/>
```

I don´t get any error executing the xslt, but `other_variable` is empty. Checking the content of `my_variable` doing `<xsl:value-of select="$my_variable"/>` or `<xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="ext:node-set($my_variable)"/>` I can see the data but without the xml structure, I mean I can see `bar` but not `<foo>bar</bar>`.

Is there any way to get this structure from a different path without use `<xsl:variable name="my_variable" select="//TheNode"/>`??

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:value-of`?

Comment: woohhoo!!! Thanks @michael.hor257k it worked. I had tried with `copy` but I didn´t think `copy-of`. Please, add as an answer and I´ll accept it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xsl:value-of` instruction will create a **text node** with the string-value of the selected node - or more precisely, the first node of the selected node-set (in XSLT 1.0).

If you want to preserve the structure, use the `xsl:copy-of` instruction instead.